# Comparar childnode com variável C# e XML (Xpath)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Eu tenho um ficheiro xml com várias estruturas. Tenho uma estrutura chamada `Product` que tem um campo `ProductCode` e tenho uma estrutura chamada `SalesInvoice`, dentro dela tenho um campo `Invoice`, dentro do `Invoice` tem outro `ProductCode`.

Eu tenho que comparar o `ProductCode` das duas estruturas. Se forem iguais tenho que fazer uma coisa, se forem diferentes tenho que fazer outra coisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está um pouco confuso mas expliquei o melhor que consegui, espero que entendam. Estou a usar C#!

Comment: O que você já tentou ?

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves ja tentei usar SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode so que nao funcionou precisava de uma ajuda, ja estou nesta situação há 1 semana

Comment: Poderia atualizar a sua pergunta com esse trecho de código do qual tentou usar SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode ?

Comment: Você precisa aprender os algoritmos usados para percorrer uma árvore. Sem esse conhecimento, mesmo com a ajuda das pessoas aqui será difícil resolver o seu problema.

Comment: @Renan eu sei usar algoritmos para percorrer uma arvore mas nao sei para uma situação mais complexa, como esta

Comment: Até você atualizar sua pergunta, talvez ajude(está em inglês) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890313/how-to-use-a-linq-query-to-get-xelement-values-when-xelements-have-same-name

Comment: Na verdade a situação que você tem é a aplicação mais simples dos algoritmos pré-ordem, em-ordem, pós-ordem etc. Você precisa percorrer uma árvore e encontrar os nós productCode e comparar os valores deles.

Comment: @Renan Exatamente ! isso mesmo. O ProductCode da primeira estrutura (Product) eu consigo ir buscar, já tenho algoritmo para o ir buscar mas nao consigo ir buscar o outro (da estrutura SalesInvoices). Compara-los acho que tambem consigo, so precisava de ajuda para o ir buscar e talvez guarda-lo numa variável para ser mais facil

Comment: @Renan será que me consegue ajudar nessa parte do algoritmo ? estou há 1 semana no mesmo e nao consigo. Era mesmo importante

Comment: Seria melhor você postar o seu código inclusive o XML porque imagem fica complicado dar uma solução...

Comment: Já consegui o que queria. Só que agora tenho outro problema. Há ProductCodes com valores repetidos mas só quero apanhar o 1º, alguém sabe como?Aqui está o meu código:

XmlNodeList xnList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Line");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    string salescode = xn["ProductCode"].InnerText;
                    if (salescode == code)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(salescode);
                    }
                    else;                 
                }